# Update two databases with liquibase command-line

Tags: liquibase

I would like to have two databases be updated when I run `liquibase update`; one being my development database, and the other being the database I run tests against. The credentials and data structure are the same.

Note that I'm not using any build automation tools, and merely using the command line.

Comment: Have your tried using two different properties files? The "defaultsFile" command-line option allows you to use different property settings, one for each database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you have two separate connections you want to update at the same time?

Liquibase can only handle one connection at a time, so you will need to run `liquibase update` twice, one for each connection.